# Would it be fair to give reputation for reviewing?

Tags: discussion, reputation, review

I was wondering why one does not get any reputation points for reviewing posts. I mean, wouldn't it be fair to reward people doing that kind of community service with some few reputation points?

I could not find any discussions on that so that's why I'm asking. Is that a discussion held in the past?

Best, Tom

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I cannot speak definitively one *why* it is the way it is.  The following is only my personal opinion.

---

Whether or not it would be fair seems to depend mainly on what one thinks reputation represents.

In my opinion, reputation should be reserved for making contributions of *content* to the site.  From the [help page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about.

Completing a review task is often done quietly in the background, and unless something very strange is not filtered out, virtually no user will take note of it.  I fail to see how this could correspond to gaining the trust of the community.  (Of course, the fact that reputation is awarded for accepted suggested edits already somewhat skews this measurement.  Even here I have noticed more than a few users make very minor edits to older posts ostensibly for the sole purpose of receiving these +2 bonuses.)

On the whole I think that having [multiple badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/227/custodian) available for completing review tasks is sufficient encouragement/reward for users to go through the queues.  (And I'd rather the queues not be populated by users looking for reputation.)

Comment: The fact that we need "review audits" to deal with people mindlessly clicking towards a *badge* is ample justification for not introducing a reputation mechanic in the reviews.